# iOS page based application clear color issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, shadow, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to make a page based application in iOS where the actual page is a non-rectangular image (contains clear color). However, the shadow that appears when I turn the page doesn't seem to ignore the transparency of the image (see below).

[Screenshot http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/9730/pagecurl.png](http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/9730/pagecurl.png)

Does anyone know if it's possible to modify this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dan, did you ever find a solution to this?  Im looking for the same solution.  If so, would you post your answer?  thx

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting your `UIPageViewController`'s `view`'s `frame` so that it sits just within the border defined by your custom page image? 
(So in your case, the largest rectangle that fits inside your white page image)

The way `UIPageViewController` handles a page curl animation with views that extend beyond its own `view`'s `frame` can be thought of as follows:

Think of the overhang as rigid. it does not bend like the rest of the page, but it does maintain the angle at the edge of the `UIPageViewController`'s `frame`. If the overhang (i.e. parts of your image or view that extend beyond the `UIPageViewController`'s `frame`), is small, the fact that the overhang animates as rigid (instead of the bendy, flexible page) is visually negligible.

However, without any further modifications, the pages will only flip when a touch is started **INSIDE** the `UIPageViewController`'s view's frame. But it would be better if it could react to touches anywhere on your white page image. If you want the pages to react to touches inside another view's frame (e.g. the view holding your white page image), try the following:

```
otherView.gestureRecognizers = myPageViewController.gestureRecognizers;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the iOS framework puts a shadow over the entire bounds of the view controller you specify for the page, so any transparent areas will look shadowed. You could try masking your view controller (`viewController.view.layer.mask` and `viewController.view.layer.masksToBounds`) and see if that helps.

Hopefully Apple improves this framework for a future iOS release. It sure would be nice to disable that shadow or have a way to do it yourself but there you go.